# Pointing domain away from google

Tags: google, domains, google-workspace

I've already asked this question on google apps support, didnt fet an answer yet, and I am in a bit of a hurry. Need to have that website up by monday.

Question:
We have a domain registered at 101domain, we used a domain just for google apps, for email, and some services, and domain was never used for website. Now we pointed domain to the local hosting service, set everything like it should be, and pointed back to google from hosting service for gmail and gmail works perfectly.

Problem is that we tried to set up a website at hosting service but domain still points to google apps login. Everything looks like it should, we recently bought 2 more domains that are set up the same (we use google apps on them too), the only difference tha I can think of is that we didn't use for apps first.

Could this be because CNAME lags behind DNS server change?

Answer (score 1):

If you post the URL we can help you debug, but it usually takes anything up to 24 hours for these changes to appear globally. You can checkout your current settings quickly with [www.iptools.com](http://www.iptools.com) in the meantime.

As I said, without being able to check on the DNS it's hard to advise.

Comment: I've already checked ip it's still pointing at google, hmmmm now I have ping the website from the iptoolc.com and it shows my local hosting server like it should. Funny thing is when I ping from command line (win 7) i get googles ip. I am guessing some places have it updated and some don't? I am in Europe     Domain is odvetnikpro  , enter a dot before pro. Had trouble last time I posted url. :p.

Comment: Ok I used a US proxy and it pointed me to the right place. When I try that url without proxy it still points me to google. I am pretty sure i just need to wait now.

Comment: @redbeard it sounds like the change has worked and it's just a matter of time.